# Replacing trimmer head on Kobalt 80 volt

Tags: string-trimmer

[image]

[image]

Can anyone help with an answer?

I am attempting to remove the stock trimmer head from an 80 volt Kobalt weed trimmer that uses a brushless motor coupled directly to the trimmer head. While I found some videos that explained this procedure very well for versions where the motor is not directly next to the trimmer head, this procedures will not work for the 80 volt version with the motor is next to, & coupled directly onto the trimmer head. On my version with the brushless motor, I see that where the motor shaft, that couples directly to the trimmer head, the motor shaft protrudes and the shaft has a slot that implies that the shaft should be held with a slotted screw driver or other tool and that the trimmer head should then be twisted & threaded off. I am unable to twist off the trimmer head as I apply force that overpowers my ability to hold the screw driver causing it to twist i.e. the shaft eventually turning. Which directing should I be turning (I thought to the right)? Also, is there some trick to this removal or should I be lubricating the threaded shaft first?

Comment: A picture of the trimmer head would really help

Comment: So your using a screw-driver to attempting to turn the trimmer head but have you tried just unscrewing with the screw-driver? Is that "shaft" actually a threaded lock nut? In other words, try the opposite. Try holding the trimmer head in place while unscrewing the "shaft" as you call it.

Comment: Been attempting to place picture for the last 4-5 hours just not working.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Yes tried both holding driver in the slot and turning the trimmer head and tried holding the trimmer head and turning the shaft with the screwdriver.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to give a remote advice, but I think you should put the trimmer in a colder place (like basement), and just wait for a day, until temperature of the head, shaft and motor get lower and equalize.

Than, you put your screwdriver like you use to do, and than gently and repeatedly try movement in both directions, slowly increasing the power from gently to harder. At some point it will move.

The head should eventually move counterclockwise, if seen "from below" (this is just like in pics). I actually can't guarantee this for your model, but this is almost the standard head behavior. In any case, my procedure says move alternatively in both directions, so what is the rigth it really doesn't matter - but eventually the head will move in the right direction - of course.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use a hammer drill with a flat head to get mine off. Nothing else worked. But once the head was off, I faced another problem: none of the replacement trimmer heads sold on the market fit this machine. This has a normally-threaded bolt that turns the head; most market trimmers use reverse threaded bolts and nuts. And the M10 x 1.25 thread size on the machine means that finding nuts that will fit new heads is almost impossible (you can buy the nut but it won’t fit many heads like those made by Shakespeare). I don’t understand why Kobalt designed a trimmer that won’t take replacement (and better) heads.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the trick. there face the trimmer head down towards the ground and look at the top (the side you would see while you are using it).

There is a small hole in the top where you need to stick a small screwdriver into that will lock the head from spinning. Then just twist the head counter clockwise and it will screw right off. Don't bother messing with the "slot" in the center of the head on the bottom (shown in your pics), that's a red herring. Flip it over and find the other hole that prevents the head from spinning.